# Why does the suggested fix for git push without upstream include the exact command, but the same for git pull doesn't?

Tags: git

Whenever you attempt to push to a remote repository without having an upstream, git returns the following (assume that my branch is called 'development-branch'):

```
fatal: The current branch development-branch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

     git push --set-upstream origin development-branch
```

As you can see, git returns an exact command which you can simply copy-paste and run. Alternatively, if you attempt to pull without having an upstream, git returns the following:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> development-branch
```

In this case, the command I would need to run is `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/development-branch`, but git doesn't return this exactly, instead opting for the `<branch>` keyword and *then* the correct branch name. Why? Why not directly return the exact command so it can be simply copy-pasted and run, like the 'git push' suggestion?

Comment: Hard to tell without asking the maintainers of git. It would be speculation...

Comment: The reason may be that your local branches are known while the remote branches may be different. Although often kept the same, they don't have to be.

Comment: @PeterKrebs does this mean that there are cases where `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/development-branch` would actually NOT work?

Comment: Depending how origin is set up I believe, yes. I have never encountered that in practice. But imagine naming your branch wrong locally. You can still push to the correct remote branch as they do not have to have synced names.

Comment: Yes: sometimes you need to give your local branch a *different name*. Consider what happens when you have *two* remotes, `A` and `B` for instance. Perhaps you're doing consulting and you have two clients, A and B, and client A demands that you send your work to their branch `marto` while client B demands that you send your work to their branch `marto`. But you're doing completely different work for these two clients, so you have `for-A` pushing to `A/marto` and `for-B` pushing to `B/marto`, in effect.